# Various buttons with the same class name get the clicked one

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to get the index of the clicked element. There are several buttons with the same class name, and I am getting all the elements with:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("unLockUser-button");
```

Result of getting all the elements with the same class name:
[image]

Now I need to get the index of the selected element, for that I am trying to iterate through the collection, but it is not working:

```
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(i);
    })
}
```

But as a result, I am getting all the time the same number it does not matter which button that has the same class name I click.

Comment: if you add the event as parameter to the eventlistener, you can use `event.target` - that is more robust than trying to get the index... `button[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {console.log(e.target)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".unLockUser-button"); // quaryselectorall will return and nodelist of button with classnaem .unLockUser-button
buttons.forEach((btn, index) => {// index will be current button index
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target, index);;
  });
})
```

```html
<button class="unLockUser-button">button</button><button class="unLockUser-button">button</button><button class="unLockUser-button">button</button><button class="unLockUser-button">button</button><button class="unLockUser-button">button</button>
<button class="unLockUser-button">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `let` instead of `var` as `i` will be the last `button` whose have this class, but `let` will closure the `i` value on each iteration.

```
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(i);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an event parameter to the eventlistener, you can use `event.target` - that is more robust than trying to get the index... besides when your anonumous function is called, the `i` is in the scope of that function, and not the value of the `i` in the `for` loop wherein you are attaching the event listeners.

Also, I would recommend changing the variable name to `buttons` (plural) since you get a list (elements in the function name - as opposted to `document.getElementById()` which is singular)

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("unLockUser-button");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        console.debug(e.target);
        //i in here is not the same as i in the for loop
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with the code below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        alert(button.indexOf(e.target));
    });
}
```

Or with this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        showAlert(this);
    });
}
function showAlert(butt) {
    alert(button.indexOf(butt));
}
```

It shows -1 if it's not a button in the same class.